# Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'department_Id' in table 'UserLogins' is specified more than once

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-code-first-mapping

```
class UserLogin
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string userName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    public virtual Modules module { get; set; }

    public virtual Company company { get; set; }

    public virtual Department department { get; set; }
}
class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DeptName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DeptGroup { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string userComputer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime enterDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual UserLogin createdBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime updateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual UserLogin updatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserLogin> userLogin { get; set; }
```

Those are 2 table configuration I used in code first approach in C# Entity framework.
But After I create the migration code the folowing configuration is created

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserLogins",
            c => new
                {
                    id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    userName = c.String(maxLength: 50),
                    password = c.String(maxLength: 20),
                    company_id = c.Int(),
                    Department_Id = c.Int(),
                    department_Id = c.Int(),
                    module_id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Companies", t => t.company_id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Departments", t => t.Department_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Departments", t => t.department_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Modules", t => t.module_id)
            .Index(t => t.company_id)
            .Index(t => t.Department_Id)
            .Index(t => t.department_Id)
            .Index(t => t.module_id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Departments",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    DeptName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
                    DeptGroup = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
                    userComputer = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 15),
                    enterDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    updateDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    createdBy_id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    updatedBy_id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.UserLogins", t => t.createdBy_id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.UserLogins", t => t.updatedBy_id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.createdBy_id)
            .Index(t => t.updatedBy_id);
```

And The following error Message is appeared: **Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'department_Id' in table 'UserLogins' is specified more than once.**
Please help me to find the mistake as I am new in code first approach in c# Entity Framework?

Comment: I see two department_id in your create  table instructions. Column names are not case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF adds `department_id` for `UserLogin.department` and `Department_Id` for `Department.userLogin` collection. Seems like the framework couldn't understand that the entities are connected by these properties because of extra `UserLogin` properties in `Department`. So just help EF to connect them with help of `InverseProperty`

```
//[InverseProperty("department")] for C# 5 and lower
[InverseProperty(nameof(UserLogin.department))]
public virtual ICollection<UserLogin> userLogin { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two department_id in userlogin table creation code delete 1 line 
Department_id = c.int()

Comment: But why did there duplicate line generated 
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Departments", t => t.Department_Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Departments", t => t.department_Id)
If I defined the class correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use an Id that makes sense to the class and stands on its own. An ID of **ID** is not unique.

Use something like this for the IDs:

```
public int LoginID { get; set; }
public int DeptID { get; set; }
```

You will have less problems with the migrations that way.